# SQL - Paging in recursive CTE but not in conventional way

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I want to apply paging or limit the records of CTE but not in the way it is generally suggested like this

```
;WITH children AS
(
    SELECT Item, Parent 
    FROM #TempHeirarchy 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.Item, e.Parent  
    FROM #TempHeirarchy e 
    INNER JOIN children e2 
       ON e.Parent = e2.Item
)
select * into #TempFinal
from (select row_number() over(order by parent asc) as RowNumber, * from children) t
where t.RowNumber between 1 and 10
```

But in this way it first apply recursion to all the records and then apply paging and so it takes a lot of time to do this even though I am fetching only 10 records.

Isn't there any way where I can stop recursion altogether when the count of records parsed by CTE reaches to 10 records?

If that is not possible then is there any other way where I can generate parent child data and stops when it reaches to the page size?

Comment: I don't see a where or filter condition on the first select.

Comment: I don't have any condition. And if I limit the record in first query itself it will not fetch the actual levels

Comment: So how do you identify the top most parent for each group?  A hierarchy by definition has a starting point.

Comment: Tips: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: How are you populating the temp table? Also, are `Parent` and `Item` integers? If the answer to the latter is "yes", I have a much better way for you.

Answer (score 1):

Generate you own counter in the recursive query and stop once count his 10.

Additionally it seems you've not limited your starting value very well.  You need to start somewhere.

```
;WITH children AS
(
    SELECT Item, Parent, 0 as cnt 
    FROM #TempHeirarchy 
    WHERE  parent is null --? Missing starting value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.Item, e.Parent, cnt+1  
    FROM #TempHeirarchy e 
    INNER JOIN children e2 
       ON e.Parent = e2.Item
    WHERE cnt < 10
)
select * into #TempFinal
from children
```

Comment: shouldnt start on `1`  or check `cnt < 10` ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
;WITH children AS
(
    SELECT Item, Parent, 1 as Level
    FROM #TempHeirarchy 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.Item, e.Parent, Level+1 as Level
    FROM #TempHeirarchy e 
    INNER JOIN children e2 
       ON e.Parent = e2.Item
    WHERE Level <= 10
)
```

Comment: Won't this limit the depth of the tree? I am talking about the number of records.

Comment: AFAIK this will limit  to 10 records returned; but without a starting point who knows what records those will be.

Comment: @xQbert Well OP say only want 10 records, I know is weird but no more constrains

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I was agreeing this should meet the need of 10 records returned, I can't see why it wouldn't work other than no starting point on initial query. even if there are "multiple" parents there must be a way to identify "those" parents.

Comment: As per your query if parent will have 10 children then for Parent record `Level` will come as 1 and for next 10 records (children) the `level` will come 2, no? So your condition will not meet until a parent with 10 level child depth come

Comment: Yes, I see that now ... but again, would be easy if you show us a sample with your desire output from start instead we spend time guessing :(

Comment: Can we come on chat? I can explain you there better if you have time

Comment: Yes, But Im a visual person need see something to process better.